# Javascript alert messages in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Alert boxes in infinite loop, here I am trying to put a popup alert message on 2 consecutive fields so they cannot be left blank, I know why it is happening - because when onblur event of 1st function is launched it gives focus to second one & when it jumps back to first one onblur of 2nd textfield is launched.

I know validation would be best when done at the form level, but this is the requirement I got.

Any help?

Javascript code

```
function x()
{
   if( document.getElementById("1").value.length==0)
   {
      alert('1 is required');
      document.getElementById("1").focus();
   }
}

function y()
{
   if(document.getElementById("2").value.length==0)
   {
      alert('2 is required');
      document.getElementById("2").focus();
   }
}
```

HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="City Name" id="1" onblur="javascript:x();">
<input type="text" name="Kitty Name" id="2" onblur="javascript:y();">
```

Comment: Why do you have `onblur="javascript:x();"` and not just `onblur="x();"` ?

Comment: Why do you have a blank line every other line, and no indentation?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of handling it in `onblur()` event, you can handle it in `onchange()` event.

If you still want to use `onblur()`, then use the focus inside `setTimeout` as shown below.

```
alert('2 is required');
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("2").focus(); }, 100);
```

Comment: I am confused as to why the timeout is necessary.  When you do a focus() without the setTimeout it seems that the field should not blur again triggering the onblur().  Can anyone explain to me why the onblur() fires again?

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental problem when trying to refocus on a field on an `onblur` when it is invalid. If the user decides to navigate away, the simply can't. When they click away from the field, they are forcibly taken back. I have seen instances where a user is forced to kill their browser session, just to escape an over-zealous `onblur` validation.

I realise this might not be the exact solution you are after, but can I recommend another approach that still involves client-side validation.

I recommend you highlight the field as being invalid in some way on the `onblur`. E.g. put a star next to it, highlight it red, etc. This way you can dispense with the `alert` and user still has control.

When the user comes to submit the form, you perform your client-side checks and display alert to them then (see @Phill Sacre's answer)

Comment: I also agree with this - onBlur validation is often annoying. Try to suggest an alternative if you can - highlighting invalid fields is often used.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: consolidate your validation into one method, and check each sequentially in it.

So (pseudo-code):

```
function validate() {
     for (field in fieldlist) {
         if (document.getElementById(field).value.length == 0) {
              displayerror();
              document.getElementById(field).focus();
         }
     }
}
```

This way you will only ever display one error at a time.

Comment: +1 For the consolodated validation. (Only 67 to go, now Phil! ;-))

Comment: If `validate` gets invoked onBlur, doesn't this have the same issues?

Comment: @Rohit: I can't see that you changed anything of substance. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tomalak It should avoid the infinite loop problem because only one text box should be marked invalid (and focussed) at a time. @Rohit I also cannot see any substantial change?!

Comment: @Phill: I disagree. When you leave a textbox, if any [other] textbox is blank, you get an error and that textbox is focused. So the blur handler fires again...

Comment: @Tomalak Thinking about it, that also highlights a problem of blur validation like this - fields which haven't been completed yet will be marked as invalid. To be honest it would be better to use a validation library such as jQuery Validation rather than something like this!

Comment: @tomalak, A running code would be great, because I tried your pseudo code & it doesnt work for me atleast in IE

Comment: @Rohit: I didn't provide any pseudo-code. I provided live code, that works for me in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Phill: I agree. This entire enterprise is a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to temporarily disable the `blur` handler during the execution of the other input's handler.

I've also replaced your HTML `onblur` with a proper Javascript solution, removed the blank lines and added code indentation.

I've also changed the element IDs, which are not allowed to start with numbers; your script would not have worked at all on compliant browsers.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("input1").onblur = x;
   document.getElementById("input2").onblur = y;
};

function x() {
   if (document.getElementById("input1").value.length == 0) {
     alert('1 is required');

     // temporarily disable binding
     document.getElementById("input2").onblur = function() {};

     document.getElementById("input1").focus();

     // re-bind
     document.getElementById("input2").onblur = y;
   }
}

function y() {
   if (document.getElementById("input2").value.length == 0) {
     alert('2 is required');

     // temporarily disable binding
     document.getElementById("input1").onblur = function() {};

     document.getElementById("input2").focus();

     // re-bind
     document.getElementById("input1").onblur = x;
   }
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="City Name" id="input1" onblur="javascript:x();">
<input type="text" name="Kitty Name" id="input2" onblur="javascript:y();">

</body>
</html>
```

Now, this script is rather verbose and carries a lot of code duplication. But in the interests of staying on-topic, I'll leave further improvements for another day.

I would also suggest not doing this at all; as James said, it's *irritating*.

Comment: Hey Tomalak, this code is still in infinite loop atleast for IE.

Comment: @Rohit: Worked for me on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

My be you have to change your way of comparison from

```
document.getElementById("1").value.length==0
```

to

```
document.getElementById("1").value != ''
```

it seems to me that length is always not equal `zero`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>

function x() {
   if (document.getElementById("input1").value.length == 0 ) {
     alert('1 is required');
     document.getElementById("input1").focus();

   }
   else  if (document.getElementById("input2").value.length == 0 ) {
     alert('2 is required');
     document.getElementById("input2").focus(); 
   }

}

</script>
    </head>
    <body >
    cityname:
    <input type="text" name="City Name" id="input1" onblur="javascript:x();">
    <br/>
    KittyName:
<input type="text" name="Kitty Name" id="input2" onblur="javascript:x();">

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function x()
{
   if( document.getElementById("1").value.length==0)
   {
      alert('1 is required');
      document.getElementById("1").focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true
}

function y()
{
   if(x() && document.getElementById("2").value.length==0)
   {
      alert('2 is required');
      document.getElementById("2").focus();
   }
}
```

So, if 1 is required, the `y` function won't be evaluated

Comment: I've made a test, and it works well in IE and FF, but strangely in Chrome. In Chrome the textbox gets the focus, but the cursor doesn't appear

Comment: You're right, it works if you click out the input, but doesn't if you press the `tab` key

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your code like this.
It can be solved.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>break alert infinite loop </title>
<script>
var e = function( _id ){
    return document.getElementById(_id);
};
window.onload = function(){
    e("test").onblur = function(){
        if( e("test").value != "11" ){
            Msg("Number[11] is only allow");
            e("test").focus();
        }
    };
};

/* fix start */
var beforeMsg = "";
/* fix end */

function Msg( msg ){
    /* fix start */
    if( msg == beforeMsg ){
        return;
    }
    beforeMsg = msg;
    /* fix end */

    alert(msg);

    /* fix start */
    setTimeout(function(){
        beforeMsg = "";
    },1000);
    /* fix end */
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>only 11 is allow</p>
    <input type="text" id="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

other code

common.js

```
if( window.COMMON_JS == undefined ){
    window.COMMON_JS = "common.js ver:1.0.0.1";

    window.AletMessage = "";
    MessageAlert = function( msg ){
        if( window.AletMessage == msg  ){
            return;
        }
        window.AletMessage = msg;
        alert(msg);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.AletMessage = "";    
        },1000);
    };
}
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<script>
var e = function( _id ){
    return document.getElementById(_id);
};
window.onload = function(){
    e("test").onblur = function(){
        if( e("test").value != "11" ){
            MessageAlert("Number[11] is only allow");
            e("test").focus();
        }
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Only 11 allowed.</p>
    <input type="text" id="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one JS and have one function which is called `onblur` event of textbox and `onblur` that event is in Infinite loop.

After that, I have declared one global variable (On the top of JS and outside the function `Var Isvalid = true;`)

In function, Performing validation code.

```
if (IsValid == true)
{   
    if validation is false.
    giving alert message.
    and updating the IsValid = false;
}
```

If the validation is true then updating the global variable. `Isvalid = true;`

In second recursion it will not execute the loop. If in next phase if blur event occurred then variable automatically set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Js Code. It will solve your problem.

```
function x()
{
   if( document.getElementById("1").value.length==0)
   {
      if(alert('1 is required')){
          document.getElementById("1").focus();
      }
      else
          document.activeElement.blur();
   }
}


function y()
{
   if(document.getElementById("2").value.length==0)
   {
      if(alert('2 is required')){
           document.getElementById("2").focus();
      }
      else
          document.activeElement.blur();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of timeouts you can disable the onBlur event on the "target" element and go back to the source element.  This works in IE.

```
function focusWithoutEvents(object) {
    // Small timeout so that the active element will be the "next" element
    setTimeout(function() {
        var activeElement = document.activeElement;

        // Save the current onblur()
        var activeOnblur = activeElement.onblur;

        // Disable the onblur event
        activeElement.onblur = null;

        // Now we can focus without triggering onblur event
        object.focus();

        // With a small delay, put back the onblur code.
        setTimeout(function() {
            activeElement.onblur = activeOnblur
        }, 100);
    }, 100);
}
```