# Javascript check e-mail address in input form just loops in Safari when validation is not correct

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari

I have a form and the user needs to enter their e-mail address in one input box. I have a javascript function that is stored in an external file which is being loaded in the head of the html file.

I get a problem with Safari (6.0.5) when I enter a non-valid e-mail address. The Alert window pops up and when I click OK it just pops up over and over again. I never get the chance to enter a correct e-mail address.

This is how my function looks like:

```
   function validateEmail()
{
var x=document.forms["theForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  document.theForm.email.focus();
  return false;
  }
}
```

And I call this function with as seen below:

```
<input type="text" name="email" onblur="validateEmail();" /></td >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.removeFocus()` then you dont have the problem anymore.

```
function validateEmail()
{
var x=document.forms["theForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  document.getElementById('alert_mail').innerHTML  = "Please change here";
  return false;
  }
    document.getElementById('alert_mail').innerHTML  = "";
}
```

EDIT: The `return false;` in this function has no effect, I assume the code you posted is not the whole code, anyway `return false;` is useful when you submit a form and you wan't to stop submitting if validation does not pass.

Comment: Should he also "return true" at the end of the function?

Comment: @AlejandroIván, in the case of an input field the `return false;` has no effect, in case there is a form being submitted in this function it will be needed. But as it is, no it's not needed.

Comment: You're right. It's called in the onblur event. I thought it was being called in the onsubmit event for a moment.

Comment: And thank you for your advice on adding the hidden DIV! This I will for sure use to make it more visible of what needs to be corrected by the user.

Comment: Varsågod! Glad I could help

Comment: :) I did not managed to get the suggestion of adding the DIV to work. I removed the alert() and thought your suggestion was much better. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Post html with the relevant code so I can help more. (besides just the input)

Comment: I do not seem to have that much characters to put into a comment? (remember me being new here). Shall I Answer my own question in order to add the whole code?

Comment: @Andreas, check here an example, changed the code a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/7GfeD/

Comment: @Sergio Have I? Have I clicked something that I shouldn't have clicked?

Comment: @Andreas, maybe you did. Was just curious why, now I know :)

Comment: @Sergio Sorry the confusion! I think I clicked the accept answer from Liam Sorsby as well and it seems that there can only be ONE accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Think there maybe a bug in safari with onblur have you tried onchange?

Comment: I've just read that the issue is to do with re-focusing to an invalid field so. However this post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356341/javascript-alert-messages-in-infinite-loop